# Typesafe Config: How resource files get merged

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

I have trouble understanding the mechanism of merging resource files in Typesafe Config.

According to the Typesafe config [documentation](https://github.com/lightbend/config#note-about-resolving-substitutions-in-referenceconf-and-applicationconf):

> The convenience method ConfigFactory.load() loads the following
>   (first-listed are higher priority):
>
> - system properties
> - application.conf (all resources on classpath with this name)
> - application.json (all resources on classpath with this name)
> - application.properties (all resources on classpath with this name)
> - reference.conf (all resources on classpath with this name)

Suppose I have two modules: `a` and `b`, and module `a` depends on module `b`.

```
lazy val a = (project in file("a"))
  ...
  .dependsOn(b % "compile->compile;test->test")
```

If both modules have a resource file `reference.conf`, how they will get merged?

Is it appending? Is so, how does it resolve conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are overriding in reverse classpath order (could not find the docs to confirm this).

```
classpath: a.jar;b.jar;

-> 

b reference.conf will be loaded first and then overridden by a reference.conf
```

This makes it consistent with how .properties files are read, the first in the classpath will be used.

I think it is a good idea to be explicit about your overrides however, either programmatically or by using reference.conf and application.conf as intended.